# counter Problem when Import data to json file with ssis from SQL

Tags: javascript, c#, ssis

I want to select data from sql and then save it in json file.
I don't want to use for json auto in my query.
I create a ssis project and call the data with data flow and then use script component to transfer it to json file, but when I run the project, receive error because one of the column have null value and I want to save null value not ignore it.

```
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings _jsonWriter = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };

        Row.json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Row, _jsonWriter);
    }

}
```

in the end I just want to save json file.